# Why do my bedroom and kitchen lights switch off or on without operating them from the switch?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I connected a ceiling Fan to my En-Suit, and ever since that night, my Bedroom and kitchen lights are switching on and off at irregular intervals. But the fan is getting power from a circuit breaker for lights, and my Bedroom and kitchen lights is getting power from a different breaker. However, my bedroom downlighters are on a dimmer. the kitchen downlighters are also on dim, but it's using the SAME dimmer for my kitchen downlighters. Which means, the wiring from my bedroom downlighter is relayed to my kitchen switch.

But the lights has always been working before. My electrician is now also confused why the lights are going at sunset almost at the same time and also in the morning almost about the same time. And those lights have never been on a timer  (although it sounds like it's on a timer).

Comment: To be clear, you hung the fan and then had to hire an electrician? Did they pull the fan down?

Comment: I think you've inherited a poltergeist ...

Answer (score 1):

Guesswork: in the absence of any timers on the premises, something is wired wrong and an exterior light with a photo sensor is completing a path.

Diagnosing any problem usually begins at, *ever since I*...

Answer (score 1):

1- You may have tied into a switch leg or neutral from another light. Is there something on a photo-cell or timer somewhere?

2- I have seen bad splices/ loose wiring act this way. As the light and heat of the day increases, the copper expands slightly and makes contact.

3- Crossed wiring. <---- most likely...

Trace your steps and check all splices. Go to the fan switch box first, and follow back to the Jbox.

4- Gremlins... old electrician joke.

5- Good luck.